# Getting error when pages are being requested

Tags: php, mysql, sql, content-management-system, mysql-error-1064

I had someone build out a custom CMS for a small site and now I can't get a hold of the developer. I get this error when trying to view my site:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
for the right syntax to use near 'order by sortorder' at line 1:

select path, title
from pages
where parent_id =
order by sortorder
```

After some help I was able to I think pin point where the problem is:

```
public function getChildLinks()
{
    $list = array();
    $WHERE_path = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
    $WHERE_path = strlen($WHERE_path) ? '= "'.$WHERE_path.'"' : 'IS NULL';
    $parentPageRowset = Axl_Db::query('SELECT id, parent_id FROM '.$this->_name.' WHERE path '.$WHERE_path);
    $parent_id = $parentPageRowset[0]['parent_id'] ? $parentPageRowset[0]['parent_id'] : $parentPageRowset[0]['id'];
    $listRowset =  new Axl_Db_Rowset('SELECT path, title FROM '.$this->_name.' WHERE parent_id = '.$parent_id.' ORDER BY sortorder');
    while($listRowset->next())
    {
        $list['/'.$listRowset->path] = $listRowset->title;     
    }
    return $list;
}
```

This is the function causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after getting great feed back from Adam I was able to really pin point what file I needed to fix and or look into a little deeper.

It turns out that I needed to quote out the parent_id variable

like so:

```
$listRowset =  new Axl_Db_Rowset('select path, title from '.$this->_name.' where parent_id = "'.$parent_id.'" order by sortorder');
```

Thanks Adam for your help

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with your `WHERE` clause; it has `parent_id =` but nothing following.  You need to provide a value into the query.

Comment: thank you for your response. Now where would I look in order to make this correction with the structure you see above?

Comment: I do not know what file this is in.  If it were me, I would search/grep the source code for this query (maybe just 'order by sortorder') to find the file that calls it. This gives you a place to start looking to add the parameter.

Comment: @Adam... again thanks for your response. I am going to go through all the files and see if I can find something that resembles that query. I'm not too familiar with grep. Or anything command line so I don't think that would be the best option for me. unless you can point me somewhere I can read how to do this. Thanks again!

Comment: I use agent ransack http://mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home but there are many free tools for this if you do not like this one.

Comment: Just installed and yes this is a nice application. I see that there are 8 files that have the text 'sortorder' but don't really see where it may be missing. Hmmmm

Comment: Well going through this it all looks good to me. Here is the file's syntax. http://pastebin.com/m71MRPyL

Comment: @Matthew, You should probably update your question with this information so that every one is able to see the whole picture, and can assist.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely the CMS needs a GET var in the url in order for the mysql statement to work.